# parentActivity handling in android?

Tags: android, android-activity

Suppose there are 3 Activities namely, activity A, activity B, activity C respectively. 
If I call activity C on click of activity A then on back-press I get back to activity A.
But if I call activity C on click of activity B then on back-press I get back to activity B.

Is that possible the same activity (activity C) has two different parent Activity back events, which work differently when its called ?

Comment: Yes its possible. Its wrong to use "Parent activity " as in terminology. Activity A and B are not parent activities.

Comment: hello sir can you suggest me what I have to do

Comment: If you want to return to activity A from activity C  - than call finish() in a method responsible of launching activity C in activity B.

Answer (score 0):

Override onBackPressed() method and you can go to any activity on backpress.

```
      @Override
            public void onBackPressed() {
                super.onBackPressed();
//If you want to go to new activity
              Intent myIntent = new Intent(YourCurrentActivity.this, YourNextActivity.class);
              myIntent.putExtra("key", value); //Optional parameters
              YourCurrentActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
            }
```

Aan if you want to go to previous activity on back press:

```
      @Override
            public void onBackPressed() {
                super.onBackPressed();
//If you want to go to previous activity
                YourCurrentActivity.this.finish();

            }
```

In case of toolbarNavigation you can use like this in your `OnCreateView()`:

```
        Toolbar toolbar=(Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_material);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(YourCurrentActivity.this, YourNextActivity.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("key", value); //Optional parameters
            YourCurrentActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);   
            }
        });
```

Comment: I want this function on parentActivity click button on toolbar ? so its possible to do

Comment: @mahaksinghvi yes you can do that. check the updated answer.

Comment: thanks for this answer but still I'm in same situation  that if two different activities are calling same class but on back press they got the same same activity from which its called